# ASP.NET Entity Framework .Where() with Lesser than

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How can I make this lesser than or equal work in my .Where() clause? I am getting an error.

```
var filteredProducts = Products.Where(p => p.State.Contains("Bruikbaar"))
                               .Where(p => p.Privilege <= ui.GetPrivilegeNumber())
                               .ToList();
```

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetPrivilegeNumber()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I hope this question is never asked before. Googled couldn't find it either or I am using the wrong words to express my problem.

Comment: What's wrong with this: `var filteredProducts = Products.Where(p => p.State.Contains("Bruikbaar") && p.Privilege <= ui.GetPrivilegeNumber()).ToList();` What is not working with it?

Comment: When you have results which are different from expected, or when you get an error, then you should describe what results you have now and what are your expectations.

Comment: This error:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetPrivilegeNumber()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What are the data types of `p.Privilege` and `ui.GetPrivilegeNumber()`? You can't compare apples and pears with `<=`, so to speak.

Comment: @6kgstront No need to edit your question with things like "question solved", just upvote and/or accept any answers you find useful.

Comment: @DavidG Yea I know.
But I have to wait 5 minutes to select an correct answer.
So I was planning to change the post and select an answer in 5 minutes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `ui.GetPrivilegeNumber()` outside of the query. You can also merge those `Where` queries into a single one:

```
var privilegeNumber = ui.GetPrivilegeNumber();
var filteredProducts = Products.Where(p => 
        p.State.Contains("Bruikbaar")
        && p => p.Privilege <= privilegeNumber)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Solved the issue and improved the code. Should be the answer.

Comment: Nope, will not compile. You will get something like *cannot cast lambda to bool*. Correct code is `Products.Where(p => p.State.Contains("Bruikbaar") && p.Privilege <= privilegeNumber).ToList();`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Oops, missed the parenthesis thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`ui.GetPrivilegeNumber()` is not a recognized method.

Use this:

```
var uiPrivilege = ui.GetPrivilegeNumber();

var filteredProducts = Products.Where(p => p.State.Contains("Bruikbaar"))
    .Where(p => p.Privilege <= uiPrivilege)
    .ToList();
```

And as other users mentionted, you can optimize your `Where`.

Answer (score 3):

EF does not execute method calls which you use in predicates. It stores them as expression (i.e. syntax tree) and then analyzes this tree to build SQL query by translating C# code to SQL code. It cannot translate `GetPrivilegeNumber()` method call into SQL, because there is no appropriate SQL code for that. So all you need is move this method call out of expression and pass only result of method call instead:

```
var privilegeNumber = ui.GetPrivilegeNumber();
var filteredProducts = Products.Where(p => p.State.Contains("Bruikbaar"))
                               .Where(p => p.Privilege <= privilegeNumber)
                               .ToList();
```

Now `privilegeNumber` is just an integer variable which is translated into SQL parameter

```
SELECT * FROM Products p    
WHERE p.State LIKE '%Bruikbaar%' AND p.Privilege <= @privilegeNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for the background information.
I understand EF a little more now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use other evaluation method inside LinQ. To simplified the code, you can use it in little old way of writing LinQ.

```
var uiPrivilege = ui.GetPrivilegeNumber();

var filteredProducts =(from p in Products
                       where p.State.Contains("Bruikbaar") && p.Privilege <= uiPrivilege
                       select p).ToList();
```

The above query generate same output but easy to understood.